# how to get checkbox value of checkbox that is a result of mysql query

Tags: jquery

i have a number of checkbox which are a result of fetch query and .html() to insert in a div . My problem is that i can't get the value of the checkboxes

any idea how can i get this done would be very much appreciated

Here's how i fetch my checkbox

```
<div class="subjectlist2" >
 <table class="table subjectlist">
<?php 
 foreach (editThis($value) as $data) {

?>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkme" name="czech" value = "<?php echo $data['subject_name']; ?>"></td>
  <td><?php echo $data['subject_name']; ?></t>
 </tr>
<?php
 }
?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: element ID must be unique

Comment: @Adeel any idea how to get this done i've been stuck for 2 days

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**:

```
var checkboxVal = $('#checkme').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get value of `Checkbox` you could use `.val()`. Example is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     alert( $('.subjectlist td input [type=checkbox]').val()); 
     // Will show meesage with value of checkbox
</script>
```

Comment: it's not working i think it's because the checkboxes are a result of ajax query will that have any effect